# Como fazer uma ação no jquery esperar outra terminar para começar?

Tags: jquery, funções

Estou tentando criar um menu onde a barra de busca aparece apenas depois que as `li's` do menu somem, para isso, me recomendaram a função `.delay()` do `jquery`, porém não estou conseguindo realizar estes efeitos, ela joga de forma direta a busca e remove de forma direta as `li's`

JQuery

```
$('#abre-busca').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#menu-principal-sub li').css({'opacity':0});
    $('#menu-principal-sub li').css({'display':'none'}).delay(500);
    $('#menu-principal-sub form').css({'display':'inline-block'}).delay(500);
    $('#menu-principal-sub form').css({'opacity':1}).delay(500);
})
```

HTML

```
<ul id="menu-principal-sub">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quem somos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Como participar</a></li>
    <li><href="" id="abre-busca">Busca</a></li><!-- chamada da busca -->
    <form id="barra-busca"><!-- Form de busca -->
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text">
            <button type="submit"></button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</ul>
```

Como poderia fazer tal efeito ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode tentar usando o `setTimeout()`

```
$('#abre-busca').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#menu-principal-sub li').css({'opacity':0});
    $('#menu-principal-sub li').css({'display':'none'})

    setTimeout(function(){
          $('#menu-principal-sub form').css({'display':'inline-block'});
          $('#menu-principal-sub form').css({'opacity':1});
    }, 500);
})
```

Comment: como eu poderia fazer, para que ao clicar fora do formulário ele realizasse o inverso 
?